# Does iAd integration requires any registration or ad setup?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I have followed this tutorial and added iAd to my app:
http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/

But the iAd banner is neither showing in simulator nor in device. My simulator is 4.0.2 and device is 4.1.
I haven't setup anything in iTunes connect yet.

What can cause the problem?
Do I need anything related to itunes connect or development portal?
If yes then how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to sign a contract, via the iTunesConnection portal.

Also iADs arn't available in all countries, I live in the Netherlands and have never seen an iAd in my apps.

Comment: I don't think that this is accurate. iAd is available in some countries outside the US.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few tidbits about iAd:

- To use iAd, you need to set it up for your app in the iTunes Connect portal. This includes signing/agreeing to a contract.
- Something to note is that apps that use iAd (and Game Center, for that matter) require a unique bundle ID, as opposed to a wildcard one.
- Also, test ads are shown during development. Real ads are only served to live apps. If your app is live and still getting test ads, contact Apple.
- iAd is not available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In non-app store versions of your app iAd will download a test advertisement. If it is not visible it will log complaints, check the console. Also check the delegate methods that iAd uses.

Answer (score -1):

No it does not require set up.

Comment: does not require setup for test mode. to go live in the app store with iads you need account setup on itunesconnect.apple.com