# iAd not working on iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

I'm brand new to iOS dev so please excuse my possibly extremely silly question.

I uploaded my app, QuikRGB, around 10 days ago and this morning it was finally pushed to the app store.

When running the app on a simulator or a device, it shows me this really pretty blue banner with ***You're connected to the iAd network*** on it.

On iTunes Connect: ***Live: This app is receiving live ads.***

I read in every question that people "test" iAds on their devices. I'm assuming there's something I missed, or that I'm not doing right.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you register? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343876/does-iad-integration-requires-any-registration-or-ad-setup?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check this 2 things:

1. you need to set up iAd your app in the iTunes Connect portal.
2. Also iAd is not available in all countries.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I have already signed the contract, ages ago, through iTunes Connect and given my bank details etc.